# Python DateTime Type Days Difference

Tags: python, pandas

**Data**

I import a date from an Excel workbook and store it in a variable called `reportdate`.

```
reportdate = pd.read_excel(file, header=None,  nrows= 1, use_cols = 'A:B').dropna(axis=1, how='all').loc[0,1]
```

I then convert `reportdate` to a DataFrame using `rdf = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[reportdate]})`.

`type(reportdate)` returns `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`. 
`reportdate` returns `Timestamp('2019-12-02 07:19:07.703000')`.

I don't know how to recreate `reportdate` to be that exact format and timestamp format.

Here is a sample data set.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CN ON': ['WD-D5','JF-04','P5'],
                   'Date Range': ['10/05/2019 - 11/06/2019','09/05/2019 - 12/15/2019','05/09/2019 - 10/25/2019']                   
        })
```

**What I do**

I then parse apart `Date Range` to get the last date in the range and convert it to a `datetime` type.

```
df['End Date'] = df['Date Range'].str[-10:]
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'], errors='coerce')
```

I need to calculate the day difference between `reportdate` and `End Date`.

**What I try**

Here is what I try.

```
df['ReportDate'] = reportdate
df['ReportDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ReportDate'], errors='coerece')
df['Days'] = df['End Date'] - df['ReportDate']
```

Then I check the types.
`df.dtypes` returns `datetime64[ns]` for both `ReportDate` and `End Date`.

**What I need**

I need the difference in days to be an integer or float because I need to check if those days are between certain values.

I keep getting the following error `TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<U10') and dtype('<M8[ns]')`.

Any guidance on how I can get the days difference between the dates in a number (int, float, etc.) format would be greatly appreciated. I don't know where my `TypeError` is throwing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by errors='coerce'. I searched and someone said 'coerce' is a leftover from old-version python. Try to remove it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'CN ON': ['WD-D5','JF-04','P5'],
                   'Date Range': ['10/05/2019 - 11/06/2019','09/05/2019 - 12/15/2019','05/09/2019 - 10/25/2019']
        })


df['End Date'] = df['Date Range'].str[-10:]
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])

df['ReportDate'] = '2019-12-02 07:19:08'
df['ReportDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ReportDate'])
df['Days'] = df['End Date'] - df['ReportDate']

print(df)
```

Comment: My problem is I have to use that `reportdate` from that file. This is what it looks like in Excel `2019-12-02  07:19:08`. I then read that value in using `reportdate = pd.read_excel(file, header=None,  nrows= 1, use_cols = 'A:B').dropna(axis=1, how='all').loc[0,1]`. Then, I create a new column using`df['ReportDate'] = reportdate' ` and then 
`df['ReportDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ReportDate'], errors='coerece')`. I get that `TypeError` when I try to subtract the dates.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! If you update your answer, I'll mark it as the answer!